# Mortarboard not gained with documentation rep

Tags: bug, documentation, badges

I received 200+ rep (capped) on the first public beta day of documentation, since I participated in the private beta. I just noticed, that there is a badge for reaching the daily cap for the first time ([Mortarboard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard)) and I didn't receive it.

I'm totally fine with not getting it, since documentation rep is kind of "cheated", anyway, but is this intended behaviour?